# Is there a way to access and change a value in a custom control that was added, programmatically, to a panel?

Tags: c#, reference, custom-controls

How can I change the check box "checked" value, in a custom control, after programmatically adding it to a table?

I have a custom control that has a text box and a check box. (I don't have enough of a reputation to post an image but here's a shot)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ArHN.jpg

It has a check box and a textbox.

There's a public method, in that class, that allows for setting the checkbox to either true or false:

```
public void setCheckBox(bool set)
{
    checkBox1.Checked = set;
}
```

In another class, the main class, I have a loop that adds a bunch of these custom controls to a panel:

```
private void DrawInputBits()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {

                    currentTag = tagsFile[tagIndex];
                    tagIndex++;
                    CustomControl.BitsControl newBits = new CustomControl.BitsControl(i, j, currentTag, false);
                    InputBitsTable.Controls.Add(newBits);
                }
            }

        }
```

If you can't tell, Each check box holds the value of a bit in a 32-bit number for 4 numbers (hence the nested loops 0-31, 4 times) and the point is to show or control the values. You can ignore the code about the tags. All that's doing is reading text from a file and populating the text box with that read text.

When the code is executing, if a bit's state changes, the checkbox should also change state. The following loop will be modified to go through an array of int's (4 ints) and update each check box after reading the state of each bit. Currently, the loop is just set to change all bits to be "true". That's not what I want in the end, but the point is, I can't even reference the custom controls in the panel to change the check box at all. I thought the following would work but nothing I've tried yet has.

```
private void UpdateInputsScreen(int[] inputDINTS)
{
            for(int i = 0; i < InputBitsTable.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {
                    InputBitsTable.Controls[i].setCheckBox(true);//this line gives an error.
                }
            }
}
```

This is the class for the Custom Control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public partial class BitsControl: UserControl
    {
        int bit = 0;
        int dint = 0;
        string tag = "";


        BitsControl(int dint, int bit, string tag, bool isEnabled)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.dint = dint;
            this.bit = bit;
            this.tag = makeTag(tag, dint, bit);
            this.textBox1.Text = this.tag;
            checkBox1.Enabled = isEnabled;
        }

        private string makeTag(string tag, int dint, int bit)
        {
            string newTag =  tag + ":[" + dint + "]." + bit;
            return newTag;
        }

        public void setCheckBox(bool set)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = set;
        }
    }
}
```

The main class is a little too long to provide but I can upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about keeping a list or dictionary to your controls:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, CustomControl.BitsControl>();
```

When creating the components add it to the dictionary:

```
dict.Add(currentTag, newBits);
```

And then try something like:

```
foreach(var tag in tagsFile)
{
    dict[tag].setCheckBox(true);
}
```

Comment: Let me give that a shot. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to mark the answer as the right answer if suitable.

Comment: I think it's working. I'm not getting an error but I'm having trouble getting the UI to update the changed values. I think that's a separate issue though. THANKS!